# Interrupt and task, timer interrupt, and tasks relationship

Tags: timer, task, interrupt, stm32

I am using stm32 timer interrupt.

**File 1:** (interrupt function)

```
static int flag = 50;

void timer_inter_handler(){    
    //...
    flag = some changes integer;// not 0, it is changed     
#if 0 // **** note    
    printf("%d\r\n", flag);    
#endif

}

int get_flag(){    
    return flag;    
}
```

**File 2:**  (other file)

```
int task1(){    
     static int fccount = 0;    
     while(1){    
        fccount++;

        if ( fccount%50000 == 0 )   
        {    
            printf("%d\r\n", get_flag());
            // ... 
        }    
     }//while(1)    
}
```

**Note:**

If this on, `task1` could print correct flag data changes. But if it is off, `task1` could only print default `50`value during system initialization for a couple of time. Then all the flag data printed is `0`.

I do not know why this happen. No other place update the var flag. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
volatile static int flag = 50;
```

The `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that the `flag` variable can change in an interrupt. If the keyword is not there, then the `flag` variable will **not** be able to change. That is why you don't see it changing. The `#if 0 printf(...)` might be forcing the compiler to access the variable.

Comment: Actually I used both volatile or not volatile, same result. I do not know why.
But inside the interrupt routine, I use some math formula like: fabs and float data. But basically interrupt routine is pretty simple. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.The problem is inside timer interrupt, hal_adc_start(read and stop), by reading adc value, the timer interrupt routine is hold.

Once I move hal_adc_read, it works fine.